# Images wont load from iOS cache

Tags: ios, caching, asynchronous, nsdata, grand-central-dispatch

So, I am attempting to save recently accessed images in the cache and load them back out if they are re-requested. The problem was the images requested from the cache did not show up but the images requested from the web did. However, after lots of fiddling I found that enclosing the cache data function up with a request on the main queue seemed to fix the issue. Can anyone explain to me why it works? I thought I would be on the main queue by default?

```
if([self.fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileName]){
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // Why does it work now?
        [self setUpScrollViewWithImageData:theData];
    });


}else{
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr download", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self setUpScrollViewWithImageData:imageData];
        [self.fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];
        [self checkCacheSize];
    });


});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
```

This is the scrollview setup method

```
-(void)setUpScrollViewWithImageData:(NSData *)imageDataToSetup{

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDataToSetup]];

self.thisImage = myImage;
self.myScrollView.delegate =self;
self.myScrollView.contentSize = self.thisImage.bounds.size; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.myScrollView addSubview:self.thisImage];
self.myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
self.myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5;
float w = self.view.bounds.size.width/self.thisImage.bounds.size.width;
float h = self.view.bounds.size.height/self.thisImage.bounds.size.height;

float zoomRatioMax = MAX(w , h );
float zoomRatioMin = MIN(w , h );

if(zoomRatioMax<1){
    [self.myScrollView setZoomScale:zoomRatioMax]; 
}
if(zoomRatioMin>1){   
    [self.myScrollView setZoomScale:zoomRatioMin];      
}

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your `setUpScrollViewWithImageData:` method.

Comment: Thank you! Added it to the main body. Didn't think it was relevant :/

Comment: Usually, UIKit methods must run on the main thread. I'm on the iPhone right now so can't try it, but try preparing the UIImage still in the background, without the main thread dispatch, and then do all UIKit stuff on the main thread.

Comment: Am i not in the main thread to begin with? Where would I prepare it in the background? Sorry I dont understand i'm pretty new to this!

Comment: Usually, you are. You can find out via `[[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]`. This was just a shot in the blue though, as I can't at first glance see anything else that could cause your problem. OTOH, you would probably have gotten an exception if my hunch were right.

Comment: Yeah I just double checked and im in the main thread already.